# Date range Increment

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to create a date range which would be used by a worker that is extracting logs and saving to a storage and after the extraction is done, I want to increase the range by a month so the new data range would be used to run the worker.

in essense what I am trying to achieve

- startDate=2020-01-01T15:04:05Z
- endDate=2020-02-01T15:04:05Z
- run worker
- worker completes for the time stipulated
- Increase the range to cover another month range
- run worker for the new range.

Comment: Here is an example how to calculate dates pretty similar to what you want.. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613101/130631

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example use your worker instead of echo.

```
#!/bin/bash

DateMin=$(date -d "2020-01-01 00:00:00Z" +%s)
DateMax=$(date -d "2020-12-31 23:59:59Z" +%s)

DateCurrent=$DateMin
while [ $DateCurrent -lt $DateMax ]
do
    TempMin=$(date -d @$DateCurrent --iso-8601=seconds)
    TempMax=$(date -d "$TempMin + 1 month - 1 day" +%s)
    echo $TempMin $(date -d @$TempMax --iso-8601=seconds)
    DateCurrent=$(date -d "$(date -d @$TempMax --iso-8601=seconds) + 1 day" +%s)
done
```